# Equal width of all Tab-Elements orienting on the one who has the longest text in it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way in **MUI-JS** to set a or calculate an equal width for all Tab-Elements depending on the Tab who has the longest text in it?

So that a Tab who has only two characters in it has the same width as a Tab who has like 30.

Thank You!

Comment: Yes. You can do that by js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is possible.
For this sake, you can pass sx prop to the tab tag with the minwidth or width.
as you know the values that has to be shown in the tabs, you can get the longest, and then pass it as a class to the tag.

the documentation about sx is in the link below:
https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

and the tabs documentations:
https://mui.com/api/tabs/